# In Swift, IBOutlet unexpectly found nil on self delegate?

Tags: swift

This problem is absolutely driving me insane, and I've searched all over with no luck finding a solution.  Please forgive what is probably a basic question...

I followed a tutorial to make a simple Geofence application.  Problem is, my MKMapView keeps giving me a nil variable when I declare it, giving me the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.

The variable in question is mapView, and the line that's giving me an issue is mapView.delegate = self

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // setup locationManager
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        // setup mapView
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow

        // setup test data
        setupData()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // status is not determined
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
            // authorization were denied
        else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
            showAlert(title: "Location services were previously denied. Please enable location services for this app in Settings.")
        }
            // we do have authorization
        else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func setupData() {
        // check if can monitor regions
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {

            // region data
            let title = "Weber"
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.703026, -121.759735)
            let regionRadius = 300.0

            // setup region
            let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude), radius: regionRadius, identifier: title)
            locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)

            // setup annotation
            let restaurantAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            restaurantAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate;
            restaurantAnnotation.title = "\(title)";
            mapView.addAnnotation(restaurantAnnotation)

            // setup circle
            let circle = MKCircle(center: coordinate, radius: regionRadius)
            mapView.add(circle)
        }
        else {
            print("System can't track regions")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
        return circleRenderer
    }

    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        showAlert(title: "enter \(region.identifier)")

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        showAlert(title: "exit \(region.identifier)")   
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers
    func showAlert(title: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: check mapView is connected to storyboard

Comment: can you select the mapView in storyboard and show the Connections Inspector for it (right panel, last icon)?

Comment: Thank you guys, that fixed it!  It was in fact in the connections tab at the top right, where I needed to add a Reference Outlet to my mapView variable.  Thank you!